# Build on macOS Sierra - absolute path

Tags: qgis, mac

I have downloaded QGIS 2.99 version and successfully built on macOS using qt5.10 and cmake3.10.1 . I have built QGIS several times on linux/windows but this is my first time doing it on Mac.

I have built it successfully with my minor customisations on machine1 and able to run from the default build path. I wanted to take this build to another machine (machine2) and when run, it throws the error and always searches for the library path using absolute paths from machine1.

I have set DY_LD_LIBRARY_PAT but "/Users/machine2/Documents/QGIS/output/lib/" but when run it starts complaining on 
"/Users/machine1/Documents/QGIS/output/lib/qgis_gui.framework/Versions/2.99/qgis_gui" is always looked as absolute path.

---

dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/machine1/Downloads/QGIS_New_Build/output/lib/libqgis_app.2.99.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/machine1/Downloads/QGIS_New_Build/output1/bin/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/./QGIS
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:

---

How do make the build in Mac so that these issues are eliminated and relatives paths are considered?

Comment: What options are you using for the cmake command? Also, is the build directory on machine2 empty when you begin compiling?

Comment: I have not specifically mentioned on cmake, used all defauts. I am building on machine1 and taking the output directory with dependencies to machine2.